# Implement a case in Python to execute specific commands

Tags: python, switch-statement

I want to implement a code in Python but I need to implement a switch case.
I saw this online (a standard example):

```
def switch_demo(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: "January",
        2: "February",
        3: "March",
        4: "April",
        5: "May",
        6: "June",
        7: "July",
        8: "August",
        9: "September",
        10: "October",
        11: "November",
        12: "December"
    }
    print switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")
```

But I need something different. I don't want to display some strings but to execute some commands, like:

```c
switch(button) { // this is a code for C structure
case 1: do some things ( not just display text)
case 2: do some things ( not just display text)
```

And so on. Can you please give me an example of how this structure is supposed to look?

Comment: You can store *functions* as the values in the dictionary, and call them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272369/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, where other languages use `switch`, Python uses `if...elif...else...` statement.

```
if button == 1:
    stuff()
elif button == 2:
    more_stuff()
elif button == 3:
    other_stuff()
else:
    no_stuff()
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you.